# Custom libraries in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade, windows-libraries

I've just upgraded my work box to Windows 8.1, and my libraries have disappeared... somewhat. I want to get them back.

The default `This PC` (used to be `My Computer`) view looks like this:

[image]

I had a library in Windows 8 called `Repositories`, and it's visible from the context menu:

[image]

but not from anywhere else.

How can I get my custom libraries to show up in the `Folders` section of `This PC`, in the Windows Explorer sidebar, or anywhere else? Have they been completely removed from Win8.1 and the context menu shown above is a buggy remnant of the upgrade process?

Answer (score 2):

**If you add Libraries to the navigation pane, then the default File Explorer pinned on the taskbar will open to Libraries instead of the default This PC.**

There is a way (currently) to enable the Libaries but you must understand Micrsoft more or less retired that navigation view so you might considering getting used to it NOT being there

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
<sub>(source: [eightforums.com](https://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/7950d1345527544t-libraries-add-remove-navigation-pane-windows-8-explorer-removed.jpg))</sub>

### Add or Remove "Libraries" from Your Navigation Pane using File Explorer

- Open File Explorer, then do step 2 or 3 below for what you would
  like to do. **NOTE**: You could also press the [image: Start Key] + E keys
  to open File Explorer.

### To Add "Libraries" to the Navigation Pane in Windows 8.1

**NOTE: This is the default setting.**

- Right click or press and hold on a empty space in the navigation pane, and click/tap on Show libraries to uncheck it. (see screenshot below)

[image: Solution]
<sub>(source: [eightforums.com](https://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/24637d1373700382t-libraries-add-remove-navigation-pane-windows-8-explorer-file_explorer_libraries.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I didn't think to try right clicking in the sidebar, and now feel quite dumb. Thanks for this - it's a cleaner solution than mine

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a sort-of fix for this, which allows you to put custom libraries in the `Favourites` section of the Windows Explorer sidebar.

In Windows Explorer:

- Go to `Favourites -> Libraries`

  [image]
- Click and drag the library you want to use into the `Favourites` section in the sidebar until the tooltip says `Create link in Favourites`

  [image]
- And you're done:

  [image]

The steps above won't show the library in the `This PC` section along with the others, but it's something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want add folders to the This PC folder... The one thing you can't do is remove the predefined folders: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-folders-in-this-pc-in-windows-8-1-or-remove-the-defaults/... I have great success adding folders to my This PC folder that allow me to use it as a one stop place to go to save my files.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.